# Shrink log file using powershell I get: Error retrieving databases from \ : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'SqlInstance'

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, logfile

I am creating a script to shrink log files, but when I run the script I get the following error:

```
Error retrieving databases from \ : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'SqlInstance'. 
Cannot convert value "\" to type "Sqlcollaborative.Dbatools.Parameter.DbaInstanceParameter[]". 
Error: "Cannot convert value "\" to type "Sqlcollaborative.Dbatools.Parameter.DbaInstanceParameter". 
Error: "Failed to parse instance name: \. Computer Name: , Instance "".Exception.Message
```

Any thoughts are welcome!!

My code:

```sh
#Import required modules
try
{
    Write-Host "Importing ActiveDirectory module..."
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory
}
catch
{
    Write-Warning "ActiveDirectory module not found on PC..."
    Write-Host "Installing ActiveDirectory module..."
    Install-Module -Name ActiveDirectory -AllowClobber -Verbose:$false
}

try
{
    Write-Host "Importing dbatools module..."
    Import-Module dbatools
}
catch
{
    Write-Warning "dbatools module not found on PC..."
    Write-Host "Installing dbatools module..."
    Install-Module -Name dbatools -AllowClobber -Verbose:$false
}
try
{
    Write-Host "Loading required assemblies..."
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | Out-Null
    [system.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SQLServer.Smo")
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended") | Out-Null
}
catch
{
    Write-Warning "An error occured while loading the required SQL assemblies: $_.Exception.Message"
    $currentTime = Get-Date -Format g
    "$currentTime     ERR     An error occured while loading the required SQL assemblies: $_.Exception.Message" | Out-File "$logfilePath\$currentTimeAbr$dbName.log" -Append
    Break
}

cls


#Retrieve all SQL servers in AD
try
{
    $sqlServers = @()
    $sqlServers += Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -like 'SVR-MSSQL*'" | ForEach-Object {$_.Name} | Sort-Object

    Write-Host "SQL Servers" `n

    for($i=0 ; $i -le $sqlServers.count - 1 ; $i++)
    {
        Write-Host $($i+1) "." $sqlServers[$i]
    }

    [int]$selectedSqlServer = Read-Host `n "Select server where database will be shrunked"

    if(($selectedSqlServer -gt $sqlServers.count) -or ($selectedSqlServer -le 0))
    {
        Write-Warning "You have inserted an incorrect value in the SQL Server selection menu. Please rerun the script and insert a correct value"
        Break
    }

    cls
}
catch
{
    Write-Warning "Error While Retrieving SQL Servers: $_.Exception.Message"
    Break
}

#Get and list all running instances on the selected SQL server
try
{
    $instances = @()
    $instances = (Get-Service -ComputerName $sqlServers[$selectedSqlServer-1] -Name MSSQL* | Where-Object Status -eq 'Running' | foreach {$_.Name -as [string] -replace '^.*\$'})

    for($i=0 ; $i -le $instances.count - 1 ; $i++)
    {
        Write-Host $($i+1) "." $instances[$i]
    }

    [int]$selectedInstance = Read-Host `n "Select instance where database is to be shrunked"

    cls
}
catch
{
    Write-Warning "Error while retrieving MSSQL instances on the $sqlServers[$selectedSqlServer-1] Server: $_.Exception.Message"
    Break
}

#Prompt user for other database restore related information
[char]$dbType = Read-Host "Is this a log file database (l) or a data file (d)? "

#Establish Connection to MSSQL server for editing database extended properties 
try
{
    $sqlServerConn = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") "$sqlserver\$instance"
}
catch
{
    Write-Warning "Unable to connect to $sqlserver\$instance : $_.Exception.Message"
    $currentTime = Get-Date -Format g
    <#"$currentTime     ERR     Unable to connect to $sqlserver\$instance : $_.Exception.Message" | Out-File "$logfilePath\$currentTimeAbr$dbName.log" -Append #>
    Break
}

#If database is a log, prompt user for  file network path
if($dbType -eq "l")
{
    [string]$logFile = Read-Host `n "Log File Network Path: "
}
elseif($dbType -eq "d")
{
    Write-Warning "Data files cannot be shrunk"
    $currentTime = Get-Date -Format g
    "$currentTime     ERR     An error occurred while creating the $dbName database on $sqlserver\$instance : $_.Exception.Message" 
    Break
}
else
{
    Write-Warning "An incorrect value for database type was inserted. Please re-run the script and select a correct value for the database type"
    $currentTime = Get-Date -Format g
    "$currentTime     ERR     An incorrect value for database type was inserted. Please re-run the script and select a correct value for the database type"
    Pause
    Break
}

cls

#If a database with the same name already exists within the selected instance, prompt user for database deletion. Otherwise, continue with regular restore
try
{
    $getExistingDbs = Get-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance "$sqlserver\$instance"
}
catch
{
    Write-Warning "Error retrieving databases from $sqlserver\$instance : $_.Exception.Message"
    $currentTime = Get-Date -Format g
    "$currentTime     ERR     Error retrieving databases from $sqlserver\$instance : $_.Exception.Message" 
    Break
}


#Shrink database process
if($dbType -eq "l")
{
    Write-Host "Now shrinking the $logFile database log files"
    $currentTime = Get-Date -Format g
    "$currentTime     INF     Now shrinking the $logFile database" 
    try {
        
        Invoke-DbaDbShrink -Path "$logFile" -DestinationDataDirectory "D:\$instance\$dbName" -DestinationLogDirectory "D:\$instance\$dbName" -FileGroup "$FileGroupName" -FileName "$FileName"  -Size "$ShrinkSizeMB" -Increment "$ShrinkIcrementMB = 10"
        }

        catch {

        }
    
    $Filegroup = $DBLogName.filegroups[$FileGroupName]
    $File = $Filegroup.Files[$DBLogName]
    'Datafile size properties'
    $File.AvailableSpace/1024
    $File.Size/1024
    $File.UsedSpace/1024
    }
    if($SizeMB - $file.AvailableSpace -le $ShrinkSizeMB)
{
    while ($SizeMB -ge $ShrinkSizeMB)
    {
        $File.Shrink($SizeMB - $ShrinkIncrementMB, [Microsoft.SQLServer.Management.SMO.ShrinkMethod]::Default)
        "$sqlserver\$instance".Refresh()
        $logFile.Refresh()
        $File.Refresh()
        $SizeMB = $File.Size/1024
        "Size after shrink = $SizeMB"
    }
}


#Notification that shrunk/db process was completed
if($dbType -eq "l")
{
    Write-Host "The database shrink process for the $dbName database on $sqlserver\$instance was executed successfully"
    $currentTime = Get-Date -Format g
    Break
}
elseif($dbType -eq "d")
{
    Write-Host "Remember to only shrunk log files $dbName database on $sqlserver\$instance was executed unsuccessfully"
    
    Break
}
```

Comment: Probably along with the error message you get you get the position where the error occurs. So you may shrink the code you post here to the [mre] to prevent forcing people willing to help you to digg into this big chunk of code to debug it.  ;-)

Comment: To add to Olaf's comment: `Get-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance "$sqlserver\$instance"` uses variables `$sqlserver` and `$instance`, neither of which are defined in your script, so you're in effect passing `"\"`. There are other problems with your code.

Comment: Please also read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).